# JQuery Validate Input with certain class

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate input fields when the value is empty. I want to only target input fields using a certain class. I have tried to use .hasClass("required") without any success.

I hope somebody can help.

EDIT = Should of pasted the rest.

Comment: You wrote all that but you don't know how to select by class?! `$('.className')...`

Comment: `if $(this).hasClass("required")...` What's the problem? I'm having difficulties to understand where is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from:

```
$('input').each(function() {
```

to:

```
$('input.yourclassname').each(function() {
```